# Android: I got problems with the Back Button

Tags: android

I'm creating an app on android for viewing the image with the sound when I select the next button to show the new image and the back button to show previous image but when the press the next button to the maximum index , i want it to show the start from first image index and when the press the back button to the minimum index, i want it to show the start from maximum image index. I have problem when i click the back button go to 0 index i want it show the image from the final index and also when i click the next button go to final index i want it show the from the 0 index. **But when i click back button nothing happen so what i have to do with Back Button**

```
 public void btn_click(View v){
 if (v == btn_next){
        if((IMAGE_IDS.length)> currentimageindex){
            try{
            imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
               mp.start();
              currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
              currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
            }
        catch(Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           }
          if((IMAGE_IDS.length)== currentimageindex){
                try{
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex=0]);
                       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex=0]);
                       mp.start();
                       currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                       currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                    }
                catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }                 
          }
    if (v == btn_back) {
        if(currentimageindex!=0){
            try{
            imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
               mp.start();
                  currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length -1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                  currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length -1) % myMusic.length;
            }
        catch(Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           }
        if((currentimageindex)==0){
            try{
                  imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                   mp.start();                  
                  currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length -1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                  currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length -1) % myMusic.length;
                }
            catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we indent it correctly, we get this;

```java
public void btn_click(View v) {
        if (v == btn_next) {
            if ((IMAGE_IDS.length) > currentimageindex) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if ((IMAGE_IDS.length) == currentimageindex) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex = 0]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex = 0]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if (v == btn_back) {
                if (currentimageindex != 0) {
                    try {
                        imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                        mp.start();
                        currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length - 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                        currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length - 1) % myMusic.length;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if ((currentimageindex) == 0) {
                    try {
                        imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                        mp.start();
                        currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length - 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                        currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length - 1) % myMusic.length;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It looks like you're checking if `v == btn_back` inside your `v == btn_next` statement. You need to close your `v == btn_next` statement like so:

```java
public void btn_click(View v) {
        if (v == btn_next) {
            if ((IMAGE_IDS.length) > currentimageindex) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if ((IMAGE_IDS.length) == currentimageindex) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex = 0]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex = 0]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        if (v == btn_back) {
            if (currentimageindex != 0) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length - 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length - 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if ((currentimageindex) == 0) {
                try {
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                    mp.start();
                    currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length - 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                    currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length - 1) % myMusic.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```